# Problems using POST for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I have this Operation contract

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/post/address/")]
        ADE.Address GetPostAddress(PostContract DataContract);
```

Here is the DataContract

```
[DataContract]
    public class PostContract
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string k { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string source { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int isUrl { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ISO2Code { get; set; }
    }
```

I try from a console application to execute this using

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{               
   var data = new NameValueCollection();
   data["k"] = "bla bla bla";
   data["source"] = "test text";
   data["isUrl"] = "0";
   data["ISO2Code"] = "be";

   var response = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:83/Ade.svc/post/address/", data);

   var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
   }
```

I keep getting a 400 error response. I have the same service using `GET` and that works perfect, just sometimes the `source` exceeds 2000 characters, hence, i must make use of the `POST`.

Anything obvious ive missed?

Comment: Omit the leading slash and try `UriTemplate = "post/address/"` instead...

Comment: @Roy, Still same error

Comment: Would WCF be confused by the parameter name `DataContract` (which is in fact a type name)? That would be surprising, but just to make sure, could you change its name to something meaningless?

Comment: Changed it to dc but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad request response was because of wrong content type. Had to switch from `Webclient` to `httpWebRequest`

I could then set the `ContentType` to `"application/json"` which was needed. I could not change the header `Content-Type` using `Webclient`.

Below code works:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:83/Ade.svc/post/address");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
               {
                   string json = "{\"k\":\"key\"," +
                       "{\"source\":\"test test\"," +
                       "{\"isUrl\":\"0\"," +
                       "\"ISO2Code\":\"be\"}";

                   streamWriter.Write(json);
                   streamWriter.Flush();
                   streamWriter.Close();
               }

  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
     {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();    
     }
```

**UPDATE**
In order to avoid bad request beacuse of invalid chars in string, create a custom class, and `SerializeObject` using Json.

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                        {
                            //
                            // Create new reques object
                            //
                            RequestObject rObj = new RequestObject();
                            rObj.k = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["restkey"].ToString();
                            rObj.source = row["SearchText"].ToString();
                            rObj.isUrl = "0";
                            rObj.ISO2Code = "be";

                            streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rObj));
                            streamWriter.Flush();
                            streamWriter.Close();
                        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this :

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "PostContract")]
public class PostContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "k")]
    public string k { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "source")]
    public string source { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isUrl")]
    public int isUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ISO2Code")]
    public string ISO2Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why would this help?  `[DataContract]` marks the object as serializable, using `DataContractSerializer`.  `[Serializable]` uses `XmlSerializer`.  Both serialize, but the implementation is different.